# Links in .docx document stopped working in my Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, hyperlink

For past about 2-3 days when I click any link in my .docx document, instead of visiting an actual page, my Word 2010 shows me the following error message:

[image]

This was happening for me in Word 2013 and Word 2010.

I have correctly identified that this problem is related to removal of Internet Explorer 10 from my Windows 10. However, installing this optional feature back only resolved my issue in Word 2013. In Word 2010 links are still not working, showing this error. What can I do about it?

Comment: Have you tried the steps described at, e.g. https://appuals.com/this-operation-has-been-cancelled-due-to-restrictions-in-effect-on-this-computer/ NB, there is a link to an MS help page with a fixit there -although that page is about Outlook it seems that the same fix also applies to other Office programs. I have seen other claims that the problem can result from changing your default browser.

Comment: Have you uninstall Chrome, Firefox? If yes, please install them back, then set IE as a default browser. If not, please locate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.html` in Registry Editor, back up this registry key first, then make sure the value of **Default** is **htmlfile**, the same for the .htm, shtml, .xht, .xhtml, .xhtm keys.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for a guide and a niff of information. I haven't uninstalled or changed default browser for years. I am using Chrome as default browser for about 5-8 years. I did get rid off Internet Explorer 11 (from Windows additions section), since I now have and use Chrome (default browser) and Edge (supporting Browser). But I did this 2-3 months ago (when installing Windows 10), not just past week. These links were working then (past few weeks ago).

Comment: If the solution is to change default browser for file formats mentioned by Emily to IE then I don't want to do this, because I don't want to use IE. Neither as default nor as any kind of browser in my system.

Answer (score 0):

As in the question, bringing Internet Explorer 11 back to Windows 10 only resolved this issue for Word 2013. For Word 2010 a serie of changes in Windows Registry are required in order to change some keys' values.

To do this either use .reg file mentioned [here](http://onezeronull.com/2020/02/21/this-operation-has-been-cancelled-after-clicking-a-link-in-word-2010/) or perform necessary steps by yourself:

1. Run Registry Editor.
2. Navigate to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.html`.
3. Double click the `(Default)` item in the right pane to start editing it.
4. Make sure that its value is set to `htmlfile`.
5. Repeat steps 2-4 for `.htm`, `.shtml`, `.xht`, `.xhtml` and `.xhtm` keys in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\`.
6. You need to restart Windows, after you done, for the change to take effect.

The last point, i.e. restarting Windows, is essential. Initially I skipped it and the solution seemed to be not working. After Windows restart the issue was fully resolved.

I have found the solution in [this blog article](http://onezeronull.com/2020/02/21/this-operation-has-been-cancelled-after-clicking-a-link-in-word-2010/). It is from February 2020.